# AMMaps - how to use target= _blank

Tags: amcharts, ammap

I am able to set theURL to be clicked when someone clicks on a province but it opens in the current window, I would like it to open in 'new' or '_blank'.

```
"dataProvider": {
      "map": "canadaHigh",
      "areas": data,
      "urlField": "url",
      "urlTarget": "new"          
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set `urlTarget` at the `mapData`/`dataProvider` level. Unfortunately the documentation is a bit misleading at the moment. I notified the team about this and they're looking into it.

The correct way to set the `urlTarget` is in each individual [`mapArea`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapArea#urlTarget)/[`mapImage`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapImage#urlTarget), for example:

```
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "areas": [{
      "id": "CA",
      "urlTarget": "_blank",
      "url": "http://google.ca"
    }, {
      "id": "US",
      "urlTarget": "_blank",
      "url": "http://google.com"
    }]
  },
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/75e6d4ffa6dde8bf4008eebd310f8e6f?editors=0010)